# Boolean array in If guard

Tags: apl, dyalog

According to the Dyalog APL language reference

> the test condition to the right of :If must return a single
> element Boolean value 1 (true) or 0 (false)

Is there any particular reason why the value is allowed to be an array rather than requiring it to be a scalar? Is it only for convenience? Do other other APL dialects which implements the If statement also allow non-scalar guards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A scalar is a 0-dimensional array.)

A few more details to expand on [Jürgen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76210397/5306507):

It is very common to have 1-element vectors where a scalar is actually appropriate. This is especially true in APLs that do not have the monadic `≢` ([Tally](https://apl.wiki/Tally)) function (including Dyalog prior to version 14.0), prompting people to use `⍴` ([Shape](https://apl.wiki/Shape)) instead. For the same reason, allowing a 1-element array ([singleton](https://apl.wiki/singleton)) is widely allowed in many contexts where, strictly speaking, a scalar would be required. This is known as [singleton extension](https://apl.wiki/singleton_extension). Here are some examples of constructs that give a 1-element vector when one would actually want a scalar:

- Checking the length of a vector with `42=⍴myList`
- Picking the first element of an array with `1⍴myTable`
- Getting the second element of a 2-element vector with `1↓myPair`
- Computing the rank of an array with `⍴⍴myArray`

Indeed, it was traditionally quite awkward to get a scalar, and this leniency was therefore a very welcome convenience. Some APLs didn't (and still don't!) have `⍬` for the empty numeric vector, but `⍴` was lenient about types and allowed `''` so the shortest contruct was the unintuitive `''⍴expression`. Today we have `⊃` or `↑`  as [first](https://apl.wiki/First) (depending on dialect).

Before control structures were added to various APLs (some still don't have them!), the only flow control was `→` ([Branch](https://apl.wiki/Branch)) which was defined as "go to the first line number in the array on the right, if any; do nothing if empty", allowing various computational methods to select branching destination. For example:

```
 →(0=⍴⍴myArray)/SCAL
⍝ code for non-scalar arrays
 →ENDIF
SCAL:
⍝ code for scalars
ENDIF:
```

The new control structures had to allow easy conversion of existing code and support common patterns:

```
 :If 0≠⍴⍴myArray
⍝ code for non-scalar arrays
 :Else
⍝ code for scalars
 :EndIf
```

I don't have access to APL+, but APLX also allows 1-element vectors — not other singletons. As far as I know, it is unique to Dyalog to also accept higher-rank singletons.

Answer (score 2):

Many APLs allow one-element vectors where scalars were more proper. The reason seems to be that one-element vectors are returned by e.g, monadic ⍴, and the APL programmers is releaved from useless ''⍴ prefixes to convert 1-element items to scalars. First seen this on IBM APL2, I believe.